# How can I count empty cell in .csv file? if row['PredictionString']== " "

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv file with some empty cells. How can I count empty cells in .csv file? `if row['PredictionString']== " "`?

```
    submission = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'submission.csv'))

    for index, row in submission.iterrows():
        if row['PredictionString']== " ": 
            counter1 = counter1 + 1

    print('output:', counter1)
```

It doesn't work.

`output: 0`

First col name: `patientId`

Second col name: `PredictionString`

[.csv_printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCPDR.png)

Comment: Does it work for you? If not what problem are you having?

Comment: It doesn't work for me.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: This code doesn't work. `Output: 0`

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for `' '`(space) and not `''`(empty string)?

Comment: I'm looking for empty cells.

Comment: `''` (empty string) and `' '`(space) doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `submission` is a pandas dataframe (like it seems to be), you can count like this:

```
counter1 = len(submission[submission.PredictionString == ' '])
```

Without any for loops.

**EDIT:**
Considering as empty `' '`, `''` and `NaN`'s:

```
counter1 = len(submission[(submission.PredictionString == ' ') | (submission.PredictionString == '') | (submission.PredictionString.isnull())])
```

Example:

```
>> mydict = {'patientId': {0: '1', 1: '1', 2: '1'},
>>           'PredictionString': {0: '', 1: ' ', 2: np.NaN}}
>> submission = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
>> counter1 = len(submission[(submission.PredictionString == ' ') | (submission.PredictionString == '') | (submission.PredictionString.isnull())])
>> print(counter1)
3
```

Comment: Could you please confirm the name of the dataframe and the name of the column?

Comment: @Badum: Also confirm your concept of empty.  Do those "empty" cells have an empty string `''` or a single space `' '` or something else?

Comment: I don't know. I added a PRTSCR of my .csv file.